# Reducing the amount of reads in a where query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have recently implemented firebase into my project and I have created a user collection, this collection has a document for each user and each document has about 8 fields, when my user launches the app, I am trying to pull the document that corresponds to his data, so im doing the following query:

```
async function getUserData() {
        
        const _collection = collection(db, "users")
        const _query = query(_collection, where("userid", "==", uniqueUserID))
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(_query)
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.data())
        })
        setLoadingStatus(false)
    }
```

This query works and gives me the corresponding user data, but the problem is, if the user is too far down the collection, this will execute 8 reads per document until it gets to the corresponding user, I have tried to implement a cache system using a `lastModified` but I still need to read the document data for that field and it will end up using more or less the same amount of reads. My question is: How do I reduce the amount of read operations that get executed when im trying to compare values in the documents, I have also thought of adding an `a` like so `a_uniqueUserID` so it gets ordered alphabetically and takes the first spot of the document but it's hacky.
EDIT: Here is what my structure looks like: [image]

Comment: I'm unclear why you believe "this will execute 8 reads per document".  Your collection here only appears to have 5 documents.  Even if you query for the entire collection, it will only cost 5 document reads.  I think it would help if you illustrate more clearly what the specific source data is that you're working with and how you are counting these document reads.

Comment: All of my reads and writes for the day were 0, I opened up the app, the app got the user, which in the structure is the third document and read his userid, as soon as this was executed, i refreshed the firebase console and the reads were 22, so my logic is each document has 8 fields, it was the 6th field in the third doc, so it read the first doc, 8 reads, the second, 8 reads and the third 6 reads because it got the value. Hope this made it clearer

Comment: If you only want the data for one user, why are you fetching all of the documents?  If you set the user ID to be the same as their Authentication ID, you can fetch a single document, using just the ID.

Comment: A read is per document, not per field.  If you read 5 documents, that is only 5 reads.  If you triggered Cloud Functions when a document was changed, this may have triggered your additional reads.

Comment: @JasonBerryman So what you mean is creating each document with the actual ID of the user? That way we only need to query for a single document and not go through all of them?

Comment: Yes, that's an extremely common pattern.  If you already have a unique ID for something, that can be the document ID.  No need to generate a new random ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the definition of a document and a field.  When you read a document, you always get all fields out of it.  The snapshot contains everything read, even if you don't use it.  There is no additional cost per field, other than the storage required to hold it all.  In your screenshot, you show 5 documents, and one of those documents have 8 fields.

You are probably misunderstanding the metrics in the console.  When you read and write documents using the console, those are also billed as reads and writes - use of the console is not "free".  What you are seeing is a combination of what your app is doing in combination with what you're doing in the console.